# mysite.domain.com is not working on 2-server farm

Tags: my-site, alternate-access-mapping, dns

If I shutdown server A, I can't open mysite.domain.com AAM configured on Default Zone Internal URL http://mysite.domain.com Public URL http://mysite.domain.com

The DNS record points to server A only (I am not sure if adding a DNS record for mysite.domain.com pointing to server B will work). The application pool is running on server B which runs under the identity "spservice". I changed my local hosts file pointing mysite.domain.com to server B, which only worked when I restarted the UPS service. Any ideas?

Comment: Just for clarification, which version of SP are you using?

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds like your farm is set up with two WFE servers, one of which is doubling as the application server? Or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: sp2013, 2WFE win2012 on software NLB(also UPS service running on both servers as well) and i have 2 webapps (1 for intranet.domain.com& 1 for  mysite.domain.com)

Comment: hello, any ideas?

Comment: Where are users accessing the site from? Is it on a different VLAN? Is there perhaps a Cisco switch between them and the farm?

Comment: yes there is a switch. and users access my site with URL http://mysite.domain.com. how can i make sure there is HA when server down (ex: server A)? should i change AAM?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this article](http://www.deluksolutions.net/davemilnerblog/2013/06/22/sharepoint-web-servers-nlb-multicast-and-vlans-small-farm-architecture/) will help you. Basically when setting up software NLB on a small server farm, some switches (like the Cisco Catalyst mentioned in the article) have problems with multicast MAC addresses in their ARP table.

In the case of the Catalyst you can fix it with a command like this:

```
arp 172.16.63.241 0300.5311.1111
```

The article explains:

> In this command the first parameter is the IP Address of your cluster (in same VLAN as servers).  The second parameter is the MAC address of the cluster, which you can read from NLB manager.   It’s in a little different format – for example the above entry would look like 03-00-53-11-11-11 in NLB manager.  You can find this information under Cluster->Properties from the NLB manager menus.

Hope that helps resolve the issue!

Comment: is is not switch issue(it HA to access mysite.domain.com). i have a NLB cluster named "intranet.domain.com" contains server A&server B. now i want HA for mysite.domain.com. should i create another cluster with new nics on the same NLB pointing to servers A&server B? or there another approach?